# Firefox Javascript Error / Oddity / Weirdness. Any Explanations?

Tags: javascript, firefox-9

If you view this page...
http://eastlondondance.org/admin/MozillaProblem/example.php
...you'll find that there are no errors but that the functionality is not working.

The last dropdown is not being populated with options like the other 2. This however works on Safari, Chrome and IE.

What gives? Why isn't it working on Firefox Linux, PC or Mac but is on all other browsers?
Is it a problem with the code or a problem with Firefox?

Any help is much appreciated.

cheers,
George

Comment: It is working properly. Didn't understood what is the problem.

Comment: Working properly in FF9 (Windows). Can you mention which version of FF are you facing problem in?

Comment: @Ash in firefox the final dropdown is unpopulated in FF 8.0.1 for me anyway

Comment: did you check the source code view?

Comment: @benni_mac_b - I check in chrome 16 and FF 8.01. It is working properly.

Comment: This is not working for me in Firefox 9 on Mac, Linux and PC hence the post. The answer, weirdly fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox is having problems with the variable name of `performance`. While I'm not certain why this is, renaming this to anything else will allow it to display in firefox. In the example below I renamed it from performance to performancex.

Example: http://benjaminhopkins.co.uk/stackoverflow/firefox.html

From the comments above seems not everyone see the problem? Maybe it could be a extension / plugin causing the issue. Using the developer toolbar and hovering performance firefox reveals the following:

```
Performance { constructor=Performance,
              timing=PerformanceTiming, 
              navigation=PerformanceNavigation}
```

Comment: that's interesting-- those kinds of errors can really drive you nuts.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have amended the code so that it now does not use the ?keyword? performance. A weird one certainly!

Comment: @daktau Great!, you can mark the question as answered by clicking the tick next to my response